# ActualValue of Parameter Changes for All Alternatives in Blazor Application

Tags: c#, data-binding, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am building a Blazor application where users can input values for various **parameters for each alternative**. I noticed that when I update the **ActualValue** of one parameter for an **alternative**, the value **changes for all alternatives**.

**Here's a snippet of my code of a .razor for reference:**

```
@foreach (var alt in dataModel.Alternatives)
{
   alt.AltParameters ??= dataModel.EndNodeParameters;
   var altParam = alt.AltParameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == param.Id);
   <td>
       <div style="display: flex; margin-bottom: 5px">
           <div class="input-group" style="margin-left: 10px;">
               <input type="number" min="1" max="10" class="form-control" @bind="@altParam.ActualValue">
               <span class="input-group-text weight-unit" style="border-color: dodgerblue: white; background-color: dodgerblue;">V</span>
           </div>
           <div class="input-group" style="margin-left: 10px;">
               <input type="number" min="1" max="10" class="form-control" readonly @bind-value="@altParam.Usefulness">
               <span class="input-group-text weight-unit" style="border-color: limegreen: white; background-color: limegreen;">U</span>
           </div>
       </div>
   </td>
}
```

**AlternativeModel class:**

```
public class AlternativeModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double TotalGrade { get; set; }
        public List<ParameterModel> AltParameters { get; set; }
    }
```

I am also adding a screenshot for better visualization of the table that I have.
If I update the value a parameter under BMW the alue under Audi will also update.
[image: ALternatives table]

I suspect that this might be due to binding and because all the Alternative parameters have the same ID. Can anyone explain why this is happening and suggest a solution to fix it?

Comment: Observation: you may want to redesign your data structure so you can add as many Alternatives as you want and maintain a usable UI. Make cenaValue and cenaUsefullness columns, and likewise for specifikacije.

Comment: You should make your code a little more generic.  No one but you knows what `dataModel.Alternatives` or `dataModel.EndNodeParameters` are. see [mre].  With very little context, it's impossible to answer your question, other than make some very generic suggestions such as @Crowcoder has above.